# Reading an old, badly copied Mongo database raw data

Tags: mongodb

I have an old project that I want to continue, but I make a terrible mistake when I saved it: I copied and pasted all the mongo database files, instead of using the export feature. Some time ago, I tried importing those files to a new Mongo instance (in a Docker container), and it seems that either the versions don't match, the files are corrupted, or something else is happening.

When I insert the files in the new instance, Mongo suffers a crash, which keeps happening unless I remove those files from the instance.

I know I did a really bad mistake there, but I want to access that DB again. It doesn't contain anything important, but I did *lots* of mockup data that was really useful to keep working. In a normal case, I'd just run a database initialization script and programmatically add stuff, but again, things went south: I *was going* to do that script one day, but never actually did. So now if I want to create all the classes, I'll have to take some serious time going through the code to repopulate the database.

So my question is: is there any way to read Mongo database raw files, without importing them into a Mongo container? I'm not asking for an API to work with code or any fancy thing: I just want to be able to access the text of the non-encrypted fields, which are most, and then I'll manually fix it.

Any programs or ideas for this particular need?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would try installing a version of mongo that you used to create those files. Then export and import into a current version.

Comment: Usually you can simply copy all files from `dbPath` into new location and use it, i.e just start the MongoDB using the new folder. Just ensure that you have copied **all** files from `dbPath` and ensure the `mongod` version is the same or one version higher.